# Ionic reload view after modal closes

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a way to reload the current view after I run `onDidDismiss()` from that view? I've looked online and am unable to use `$scope.reload()` and even if I could I don't want to fully reload the app, just the current page.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this by refreshing only stuff that matters. In example redo a HTTP call onDismiss event to reload page with updated data

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
state.go('your-state-name', {reload:true});
```

It will refresh the view with the parameters you input or the new calculated values from your route.